# Fragment Transaction Not Adding to Backstack

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm not sure why this isn't working I've looked through documentation and it looks like this should work.

```
DetailFragment newFragment = new DetailFragment();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.phone_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();

int backStack = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
Log.d("ROBJUN", Integer.toString(backStack));
```

My log returns 0, but correct me if I'm wrong it should return... 1?

Answer (score 1):

Are you switching from a different fragment or is this the first one? If this is the first one shown, you add nothing to the stack as there was no fragment you left to put on the stack.